# Корректность работы с SQLite на Java

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

Добрый день, работаю с SQlite на java, вот у меня появился на корректность следующих строк кода.

```
static CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();

static Connection dataConnection;

static Statement dataStatement;
```

Не будет ли накладным постоянное хранение в памяти этих 3-х объектов? 
dataConnection и dataStatement далее инициализируются в первом используемом классе наследнике(наследуются все классы от класса, в котором объявлены эти статические переменные). Эти переменные используются всеми экземплярами этих классов-наследников и каждый экземпляр специализируется на загрузке определённой информации. Так разумно их делать static или лучше каждый раз при сохранении или загрузке инфы создавать локальный объект определённого классе-наследника и обходится без static'a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал бы Вам лучше создать класс Singleton для подключение к SQLite и пользоваться им из любого класса.

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;

class JDBCConnector {

    private static HashMap<String, Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();

    private JDBCConnector() {
    }

    static synchronized Connection getConnection(String pathToDB) {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            if (connections.containsKey(pathToDB)) {
                return connections.get(pathToDB);
            } else {
                Connection connection =
                        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + pathToDB);
                connections.put(pathToDB, connection);
                return connection;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Этот класс имеет только один статичный метод `getConnection`, и он хранит все подключения на всякий случай если вы будете работать с несколькими базами данных. Он хорош еще тем, что если в будущем вы захотите работать с MySQL'ом или другой базой данных, то Вам надо будет заменить только этот класс.

Comment: только сюда лучше потокобезопасный синглтон вставить

Comment: @rjhdby Спасибо за замечание

Comment: Спасибо за помощь